# Issue with QVTKWidget in Qt Ros workspace

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ros, qvtkwidget

I am new to Qt and ROS.
I am working on Qt Creator 4.8.0. I have created a catkin workspace in Qt and a `mainwindow` was created.
And I am trying to add `QVTKWidget` to the `mainwindow`. It was successfully built but when it is run, an error message is displayed.

Code: `mainwindow.cpp`

```
vtkWidget = new QVTKWidget;
ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(vtkWidget);
ui.verticalLayout->update();
ren = vtkRenderer::New();
vtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(ren);
ren->SetBackground(1.0,0,0);
ren->Render();
```

```
Error:realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007facb5723820 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7facb37d77e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x85d80)[0x7facb37e5d80]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x22f)[0x7facb37e48ef]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData7reallocEi+0x1f)[0x7facada009cf]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData6appendEi+0x81)[0x7facada00aa1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x1d6d78)[0x7facadaccd78]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(_Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_+0x2e6)[0x7facadac8b16]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x7bcc3)[0x7facad971cc3]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x106ba)[0x7facb6c5a6ba]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x107cb)[0x7facb6c5a7cb]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xc6a)[0x7facb6c4ac6a]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `vtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()` returns a valid pointer, before calling `AddRenderer` on it, so instead of

```
vtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(ren);
```

try

```
vtkRenderWindow * window = vtkWidget->GetRenderWindow();
if(window != nullptr)
{
     window->AddRenderer(ren);
     //etc.
```

Same check should be applied to the `vtkRenderer` as well:

```
ren = vtkRenderer::New();
if(ren != nullptr)
{
    //etc.
```

If you happen to spot some null pointer, see if [this post](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkRenderWindow-New-returns-null-td5728854.html) helps.

Comment: I tried checking if it is null pointer, but still the same issue persists.